# how do i move mouse to texture coordinates?

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

im using python 3.10.5
and heres my code

```
import pyautogui
target = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('target.png')
print(target)
pyautogui.moveTo(target)
```

but for some reason it just prints None
and doesnt move the mouse to the images coordinates

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it prints `None` means it didn't find the image. Check the image you are trying to find (is it properly cropped?) or try setting the confidence parameter to make a match more likely.

```py
pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('target.png', confidence=x)
# x can be anywhere between 1 and 0, the lower the more likely a match
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui
target = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('target.png', confidence = 0.5)
#start at 0.5 and then scale as needed.
print(target.x,target.y)
pyautogui.moveTo(target.x,target.y)
```

when returning location from locateCenterOnScreen, it needs coordinates, I use this one extensively, with locateonscreen to check for validity first, then the former for actual utility. I use `.sleep()` extensively as the target applications usually don't respond at computer speed.